# SQL Server client server protocol documentation

Tags: sql, sql-server, client

I want to implement a simple authentication tool for SQL Server 2000-2008 (I hope the process is the same). I need to know the exactly procedure of what is happening, which packets, headers are built & sent and all information required for the remote login process.

In short: I need the the counterpart of [MySQL_Internals_ClientServer_Protocol](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Internals_ClientServer_Protocol) for SQL Server.

Comment: See: [MSDN Tabular Data Stream Protocol Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd304523%28v=prot.13%29.aspx)